# How to edit docx document content in a sharepoint 2010 document list

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, contentcontrol

I have a Word 2007 docx document in a Sharepoint 2010 document list. This docx has a plain text Content Control named "Introduction".

I need to create a workflow which updates the text in this Content Control but I cannot find any way to access it. If a create a custom workflow in visual studio 2010, I can access the document list, the list item and its properties, but I cannot get to the document content itself.

Is this possible? Am I going about it the wrong way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you using infopath instead of ms-word. It should be easier because infopath field can be promote to SharePoint list field. Hence, you can use workflow to modify SharePoint list field.

Maybe [this link](http://www.google.co.id/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=infopath%20sharepoint&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CD4QFjAC&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff961896.aspx&ei=It7yTra2DYXRrQfg-qnjDw&usg=AFQjCNEi2hwUA3ALhwMVTIgYGat9vGajkg&sig2=OzEtkuvCSMBwpuyN3zHvhg&cad=rja) can give you some insight.